Changing xAxis Label to Month on AmCharts Bubble Pie Charts
According to this bubble pie chart from AmCharts
https://www.amcharts.com/demos/bubble-chart-with-pie-bullets/
how to change the xAxis lable to month, something like 'jan', 'feb', 'mar', etc...
I'm trying to change this line
  let xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(
  am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
    renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, { minGridDistance: 50 }),
    tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {}),
  })
);

to
 let xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(
      am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(root, {
        renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, { minGridDistance: 50 }),
        tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {}),
      })
    );

  // Set months for X-axis
  xAxis.data.setAll([
  { category: "Jan" },
  { category: "Feb" },
  { category: "Mar" },
  { category: "Apr" },
]);

But, the bubble pie-charts are gone..

Are you using the same example?

Yes, i'am..still not find the solution
